# Can't bind to 'dropZones' since it isn't a known property of 'li'

Tags: angular, module, runtime-error, angular2-template

I'm trying to take a component that I built for my app and move parts of it into a stand-alone module.  The component uses `ng2-dnd` for drag-and-drop support.  It looks like this:

**list-editor.component.html**

```
<ul dnd-sortable-container [sortableData]="list" [dropZones]="[id]">
  <li *ngFor="let value of list; index as i" 
      dnd-sortable [sortableIndex]="i" [dropZones]="[id]">
    <drag-handle></drag-handle>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
    <action-insert></action-insert>
    <action-delete></action-delete>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I'm missing something apparently, because at run time when parsing the template it is complaining that `dropZones` is not a property of `<li>`.  Notice, it's not complaining about the `<ul>`, only the `<li>`.  Also, note that I took working code and moved it into the module, so it is not something obvious about the component template that is to blame, like a typo.  So I can only assume I have done something wrong in setting up the module.

**list-editor.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule }     from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { DndModule } from 'ng2-dnd';

import { ListEditorComponent } from './list-editor.component';
import { DragHandleComponent } from './drag-handle/drag-handle.component'
import { ActionComponent }     from './action-button/action.component';
import { InsertComponent }     from './insert-button/insert.component';
import { DeleteComponent }     from './delete-button/delete.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    DndModule.forRoot(),
  ],
  declarations: [
    ListEditorComponent,
    ValueComponent,
    DragHandleComponent,
    ActionComponent,
    InsertComponent,
    DeleteComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    ListEditorComponent,
    ValueComponent,
  ]
})
export class ListEditorModule { }
```

I then import it as I do any other module in my app:

**app.module.ts**

```
import { ListEditorModule } from '@module/list-editor/list-editor.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ ... ],
  imports: [ ... , ListEditorModule, ... ],
  ...
})
export class AppModule { ... }
```

And of course, I use it in my app:

```
<list-editor [list]="theList"><value></list-editor>
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is there a bug in there somewhere?

I just updated to Angular 5.0.5.  The problem is still there.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove **`[dropZones]`**   from  li, otherwise it is treating as a input and expecting the li element to have

```
 <li *ngFor="let value of list; index as i" 
      dnd-sortable [sortableIndex]="i" >
```

Comment: Removing `[dropZones]` didn't fix it.  The error went away, but the DragAndDrop didn't work.  And again, this is code that worked when it was embedded directly in my app instead of being in a module.